# Isolate Key/Value Pair from Laravel Model Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

In my Laravel App, a poll has many poll options. I can create a collection of those options by simply running:

`$result = Poll::find(1)->options()->get();`

This query returns:

```
Collection {#387 ▼
    #items: array:6 [▼
        0 => PollOption {#388 ▼
          #table: "poll_options"
          #connection: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:8 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "poll_id" => 1
            "option_text" => "Never"
            "responses" => 54
            "is_public" => 0
            "created_at" => null
            "updated_at" => null
            "deleted_at" => null
          ]
          #original: array:8 [▶]
          #relations: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        }
        1 => PollOption {#389 ▶}
        2 => PollOption {#390 ▶}
        3 => PollOption {#391 ▶}
    ]
}
```

Within my poll option, there is a column called `responses`, which returns an integer. I need to take the collection above and isolate the `responses` key/value pair.

```
Collection {#385 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    "responses" => 54
    "responses" => 20
    "responses" => 10
    "responses" => 123
    "responses" => 33
    "responses" => 11
  ]
}
```

The [`only()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-only) collection method does exactly what I need, but I can't figure out how to structure the query when working with Eloquent models:

```
$options = Poll::find(1)->options()->get();
$responses = $options->only('responses');
dd($responses->all());
```

Returns an empty collection because the `responses` value is nested within the `PollOption` object.

I've also tried [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-flatten), but that seems to have no effect in this scenario.

Is there an easier way to return a single key/value pair within an Eloquent model collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually possible to assign the same key to multiple values within a collection. I knew this, but I wasn't thinking the problem through properly.

For future devs: the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method takes two arguments: the value you want to pluck, and a second value that gets assigned to the key. Using the scenario above, I was able to write:

```
$result = $poll->options()->pluck('responses', 'option_text'); //Value and corresponding key
```

This results in something like:

```
Collection {#386 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    "Never" => 54
    "Occasionally" => 21
    "2–3 times a week" => 80
    "4–5 times per week" => 33
    "Daily" => 11
  ]
}
```

Which ultimately did what I need it to do. Amit Gupta's [mapWithKeys()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-mapwithkeys) answer is also correct, and will land you in the same place.